# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy into dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime, date

i have a question about string conversion.
i have a textbox which the user will input with a date in this format (dd/mm/yy).

Now i have to convert it so it is MySQL friendly.

so far this is what i have done

```
currentExpDate = txtDateStore.txt; //(i.e 25/12/13)
MessageBox.Show(currentExpDate.ToString()); // for debugging
//DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(currentExpDate);
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    currentExpDate,
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string mySQLDate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

How ever it will always throws an error whenever I try to parse it. I get string exception that says string format is one it does not recognize.

If i try to input the date with this format dd/mm/yyyy it works like a charm. Is there any workaround to solve this?

thanks

Comment: `dd/mm/yyyy into dd/mm/yyyy`. Looks alright to me ;)

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact(currentExpDate, "dd/MM/yyyy" ...) when you ask the user to input dd/MM/yy? Isn't that the discrepancy here?

Comment: Actually, the user needs to input the expiry date of a product which is in mm/yy format. However i need to build my string so it becomes dd/mm/yy which later on i will have to convert it into MySQL friendly format (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: why would dd/mm/yyyy be unfriendly to MySQL if you have it localized to accept that format? I'm not too familiar with MySQL, but with Informix, we set environment variable DBDATE=DMY4/ and all is well!

Comment: @Frank, sorry i am confused here.

If i toss the format dd/mm/yy straight into MySQL i am not sure if it works. I'll try in a sec.

Comment: @username555: Is your application localized in a Spanish country?.. As to using mm/yy format: I use mm/yyyy date format for entering 'Date Manufactured" because some items were mfg'd before year 2000. You don't need to convert mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in Informix.

Comment: @Frank, thanks for replying as i expected. tossing dd/mm/yyyy straight forward into MySQL will result 0000-00-00....

No, the apps is not localized into Spanish. It just happens that the format should be like that.

So far my only solution is to build my string. So i split the string entered by the user, which is in mm/yy format then append "20" on the yy part.

FYI, the app is for consumable goods which is why mfg'd before 2000 simply not exist (no wine nor cheese is sold btw..)

Comment: @username555: But you never know if in the future they may sell items mfg'd before 2000?.. What if you needed to perform date arithmetic on your char-based mm/yy column?

Comment: @Frank, the MySQL column is in DATETIME format. It's just that for now i am stuck on how to convert dd/mm/yy format (which is from a text box) into yyyy-mm-dd (which is the acceptable format by MySQL). I will indeed change my approach as soon i have the solution to this.

Answer (score 6):

You should just use the date as a DateTime directly to store in your database.  There is no reason to convert it back into a string.

Comment: Exactly. DateTime uses 8 bytes AFAIK (ticks is long). A string is variable width. With `yyyy-MM-dd`, that is 10 bytes.

Comment: Actually, the user needs to input the expiry date of a product which is in mm/yy format. However i need to build my string so it becomes dd/mm/yy which later on i will have to convert it into MySQL friendly format (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: So why not just keep things simple: Use a date column, have the user enter the mm/  /yyyy and you default the day to 01?.. (too bad MySQL does not support date subtypes!)

Answer (score 3):

I may be missing something here, but creating your `DateTime` object using the "dd/MM/yy" Format then
converting the `DateTime` to a string using "yyyy-MM-dd" seems to give me a string in the format you are wanting..

### [image]

To answer your comment I just used the code you posted in your question and changed the first conversion's Format to "dd/MM/yy".

```
String currentExpDate;
currentExpDate = txtDateStore.Text; //(i.e 25/12/13) 
MessageBox.Show(currentExpDate.ToString()); // for debugging 
//DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(currentExpDate); 
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    currentExpDate,
    "dd/MM/yy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string mySQLDate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Is it possible to share the code you use, mine is the following which always throws exception (FormatException)

/
string currentExpDate = "30/" + dgvSupplierPurchase.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show(currentExpDate.ToString()); //For debugging
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(currentExpDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string MySQLDate= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Confused programmer is confused....
Here's a screenshot of what happened when i copy-paste your code. The only different is that my textbox is infact part of a datagridview. But it shouldn't be a big deal, i also have  verified that the cell is indeed contains the string i wanted (Hence, the messageBox.Show).

<img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/35bwg78.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic">

Comment: @username555 what is the code for your creating your DateTime Object.

Comment: @username555 I don't have a DataBase setup or your information so I can only guess. Try it with a TextBox like I did to see if it works, if it does you may need to take a close look at the Data from your datagridview.

Comment: Hi Mark, here is the code to create the DateTime object.
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(currentExpDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Anyway it's okay, i'll just use a string builder to customize it.